# How could I transform my object from my channel (spring-integration, DSL)?

Tags: spring-integration

I have got an Integrationflow which returns me a Message and now I would like to validate it in a second channel and after sending it back I would like to transform it.
But the transformation failed.

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpUserGetUserByUsername() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(httpGetGateUsersGetUserByUsername())
                .channel("http.users.getUserByUsername").handle("userEndpoint", "getUserByUsername")
                .channel("http.users.checkUserAuth").handle("userEndpoint","checkUserByUsername")
                .transform(User u -> new UserResponseHelper(u))
                .get();
    }
```

```
public void checkUserByUsername(Message<User> msg) {
        MessageChannel replayChannel = (MessageChannel) msg.getHeaders().getReplyChannel();
        User u = msg.getPayload();
        if (Authorization.isAllowByUsername(u.getUsername())) {
            replayChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(u).build());
        }else{
            replayChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(new ResponseEntity(new ApiResponse(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,false,"You are not allow to get this ressource"), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)).build());
        }
    }
```

Comment: And how transformation failed? Unfortunately you don't share that info with us... What do you expect and what doesn't work?

Comment: I will get the whole user object, but i would like to get only some properties like name, role. I get the user with all 8 properties and what i expect ist a user with 4 props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the user with all 8 properties and what i expect ist a user with 4 props

OK. I see what is your problem. You really have just missed the fact that your `.transform(User u -> new UserResponseHelper(u))` is not called at all. So, that your "transformation failed" has confused me.

So, what is going on here:

1. Your `void checkUserByUsername(Message<User> msg)` returns `void`. Therefore there is nothing to wrap into an output `Message`. And from here nothing is going to trigger the next `.transform()` in your flow.
2. What you see for your REST service, that everything from that `checkUserByUsername(Message<User> msg)` is sent to the `replyChannel` header - the place where Inbound Gateway waits for reply.
3. In case of validation failure you send some custom `ApiResponse`. Why just don't throw an `Exception`, e.g. `ResponseStatusException`? This is going to be handled properly on the REST layer and returned as an error to the REST client.

I suggest you to really return that `u` from this `checkUserByUsername()` method and throw an exception otherwise. This way the `User` object is going to come to your `.transform(User u -> new UserResponseHelper(u))` - and all good!

You have just confused yourself that `void` doesn't trigger transform and `replyChannel` is just for sending reply directly to the initiator gateway.